# Code is breaking when the incoming dataframe is empty to iterate in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code is breaking when I have 0 or no records to in `risk_shipment` dataframe.

How to fix this ?

**My code**

```
risk_shipment=result[['riskID','linkedShipments','endDate']]

new_data = {} #define new data
#treverse all rows in current data
for index, row in risk_shipment.iterrows():
    #json only accept double quotes, so convert singal quotes to double quotes
    shipment_dict_list = json.loads(row['linkedShipments'].replace("\'", "\""))
    for shipment_dict in shipment_dict_list:
        new_data.setdefault("riskID",[]).append(row['riskID'])
        for key in shipment_dict:
            new_data.setdefault(key,[]).append(shipment_dict[key])

df_expanded =pd.DataFrame(new_data)
df_expanded =df_expanded[['customerCode','riskID','shipmentNumber']]
```

Any help appreaicated.

Comment: Check if `risk_shipment` empty or not using `if not risk_shipment.empty`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, len(risk_shipment) is 0

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, How do I fix this